# 0..1 to N Referencing Relation -> Error Message I don't understand

Tags: ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

The issue is a that I am getting an error message reading:

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_dbo.Users_dbo.People_Id". The conflict occurred in database "TrialDb", table "dbo.People", column 'Id'

I try to implment the following:

- `User` may have a `Person` assigned and `Person` may have many `User` assigned
- each entity, i.e. `Person` or any other, will have a creator and a changing user set.

The relationship shold one-way, meaning that `User` does not need a navigation property for `Person`.

What I am doing is trying to add a `User` to my database which results in the aforewritten error.

Here is the `User` and `Person` class definition (abreviated)

```
public class User
{
    public int Id {get; set;}

    public int? PersonId {get; set; }
    public virtual Person Person {get; set;}

    // two self-refencing properties
    public int CreatorId {get; set; }
    public virtual Person Creator{get; set;}

    public int ChangingUserId {get; set; }
    public virtual Person ChangingUser {get; set;}

    public byte[] RowVersion {get; set;}
}

public class Person 
{
    public int Id {get; set;}

    public virtual ICollection<User> Users {get; set;}

    public byte[] RowVersion {get; set;}
}
```

My configuration classes for the two entities are as follows:

```
 public class UserMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<User>
{
    public UserMap ()
    {
        HasRequired (p => p.Creator).WithRequiredPrincipal ().WillCascadeOnDelete (false);
        HasRequired (p => p.ChangingUser).WithRequiredPrincipal ().WillCascadeOnDelete (false);

        // 0..1 : N relation
        HasOptional (p => p.Person).WithMany (p => p.Users).HasForeignKey (p => p.PersonId);

        Property (p => p.RowVersion).IsRowVersion ();
    }
}

public class PersonMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Person>
{
    public PersonMap ()
    {
        HasRequired (p => p.Creator).WithRequiredPrincipal ().WillCascadeOnDelete (false);
        HasRequired (p => p.ChangingUser).WithRequiredPrincipal ().WillCascadeOnDelete (false);

        // 0..1 : N relations - tried this as well - same result
        //HasOptional (p => p.Company).WithMany (p => p.Employees).HasForeignKey (p => p.CompanyId);
        //HasOptional (p => p.Facility).WithMany (p => p.People).HasForeignKey (p => p.FacilityId);

        Property (p => p.RowVersion).IsRowVersion ();
    }
}
```

Can anybody help me with this? It would be utmost apprciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The People_Id, which isn't in your model, indicates EF has inserted it because your fluent code is wrong. Your user table is pointing to Person 3 times, but your fluent code only tells EF how to map one FK (PersonId). You need to change the other 2 to indicate the ForeignKey assignment using either HasForeignKey or MapKey (sorry no test project readily available).

Try something like this for UserMap:

```
HasRequired(p => p.Creator).WithMany().HasForeignKey(p => p.CreatorId).WillCascadeOnDelete (false);
HasRequired(p => p.ChangingUser).WithMany().HasForeignKey(p => p.ChangingUserId).WillCascadeOnDelete (false);
```

I'm not sure what you are trying to do in your PersonMap since your fluent code references 2 navigation properties not in the model. Assuming you want 2 self references you would need similar code.